# SASS not working on Windows

Tags: ruby, windows, sass

I've used SASS a lot before, but it was through running `bundle exec compass watch` on existing projects that I didn't set up. Now I'm just trying to set up the most basic possible project myself. I'm on Windows 10. I have Ruby installed through uru, and I have SASS installed within one of my rubies. I made a directory called `sass` and a directory called `css`.

When I type `sass` (by itself, or followed by anything at all), it throws up, and I have absolutely no idea what it means:

```
C:/Ruby/ruby-2.1.3-i386-mingw32/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.5.0.pre.rc.1/lib/sass/script/functions.rb:2053: warning: else without rescue is useless
C:/Ruby/ruby-2.1.3-i386-mingw32/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.5.0.pre.rc.1/lib/sass/script/functions.rb:2059: warning: else without rescue is useless
C:/Ruby/ruby-2.1.3-i386-mingw32/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.5.0.pre.rc.1/lib/sass/script/functions.rb:2098: warning: else without rescue is useless
C:/Ruby/ruby-2.1.3-i386-mingw32/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:73:in `require': C:/Ruby/ruby-2.1.3-i386-mingw32/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.5.0.pre.rc.1/lib/sass/script/functions.rb:2049: syntax error, unexpected modifier_if (SyntaxError)
          if separator.value == 'auto'
            ^
C:/Ruby/ruby-2.1.3-i386-mingw32/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.5.0.pre.rc.1/lib/sass/script/functions.rb:2053: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end
C:/Ruby/ruby-2.1.3-i386-mingw32/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.5.0.pre.rc.1/lib/sass/script/functions.rb:2059: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end
C:/Ruby/ruby-2.1.3-i386-mingw32/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.5.0.pre.rc.1/lib/sass/script/functions.rb:2094: syntax error, unexpected modifier_if
          if separator.value == 'auto'
            ^
C:/Ruby/ruby-2.1.3-i386-mingw32/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.5.0.pre.rc.1/lib/sass/script/functions.rb:2098: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end
C:/Ruby/ruby-2.1.3-i386-mingw32/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.5.0.pre.rc.1/lib/sass/script/functions.rb:2884: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input
        from C:/Ruby/ruby-2.1.3-i386-mingw32/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:73:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby/ruby-2.1.3-i386-mingw32/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.5.0.pre.rc.1/lib/sass/script.rb:34:in `<module:Script>'
        from C:/Ruby/ruby-2.1.3-i386-mingw32/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.5.0.pre.rc.1/lib/sass/script.rb:8:in `<module:Sass>'
        from C:/Ruby/ruby-2.1.3-i386-mingw32/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.5.0.pre.rc.1/lib/sass/script.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby/ruby-2.1.3-i386-mingw32/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:73:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby/ruby-2.1.3-i386-mingw32/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:73:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby/ruby-2.1.3-i386-mingw32/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.5.0.pre.rc.1/lib/sass/engine.rb:46:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby/ruby-2.1.3-i386-mingw32/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:73:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby/ruby-2.1.3-i386-mingw32/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:73:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby/ruby-2.1.3-i386-mingw32/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.5.0.pre.rc.1/lib/sass.rb:99:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby/ruby-2.1.3-i386-mingw32/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:126:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby/ruby-2.1.3-i386-mingw32/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:126:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby/ruby-2.1.3-i386-mingw32/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.5.0.pre.rc.1/bin/sass:6:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby/ruby-2.1.3-i386-mingw32/bin/sass:23:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby/ruby-2.1.3-i386-mingw32/bin/sass:23:in `<main>'
```

The Googles aren't helping me much here. I'm great with actual SASS syntax and basic command-line stuff, but with Ruby I'm still at the "tell me exactly what to type" phase. What do I do?

Comment: have you checked https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/2359?

Comment: I happened on that page, but... am I trying to start a Rails server by running `sass`? I didn't think so, but even if so, I'm not sure how to apply the information.

Comment: Update your Ruby version to a newer one. Also why are you running Sass 3.5 RC1? Version 3.5.3 is the latest one. You should update your sass gem also.

Comment: Using a newer Ruby (223, which I already had installed) and installing SASS into that Ruby worked. Thanks!